# jQuery.validate() validating even if nothing entered

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, jquery-validate

I'm working with the validate() method in jQuery. According to [the docs](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/validate):

> If nothing is entered, all rules are
>   skipped, except when the field was
>   already marked as invalid.

and following is my code:

```
$("#Form").validate(
{
      errorClass: "dialogerror",
      onfocusout:          function(element)
                         {
                             $(element).valid();
                         },
      onkeyup: false
});
```

However it produces the error message **even if nothing is entered**, so my guess is the element is being marked as invalid when loaded, could this be true? Perhaps an option is set somewhere and I'm looking in the wrong place.

Any advice much appreciated.

Comment: I'm having a similar problem. ( http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6281380 ) I wish I could find docs on how to manage when initial validation occurs. If you find the answer to your problem, would you please post the reference you used?

Comment: @shannon - Sure I'll be adding a bounty to this question soon - that should help.  If you would be kind to upvote that may generate more interest.